# AngularJS: How to define constant in router resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to define constant in router resolve and use it within controller (by DI). but when i run project, it show error about unknown **obj** provider.

```
var app = angular.module("pikadOnlineApp", []);
stateProvider.state("App", {
    url: "",
    controller: "appCtrl",
    templateUrl: "app.html",
    resolve: {
        initData: ["$q", "$timeout", function ($q, $timeout) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function () {
                app.constant("obj", "11111");
                deferred.resolve();
            }, 5000);
            return deferred.promise;
        }]
    }
})
```

Comment: You just need to pass a value from the resolve to the controller?

Comment: It is global data and It's not just for that controller. i want inject it within everywhere. For this case, it is better to use constant or factory?

Answer (score 0):

Simply inject the constant in the resolver function, and return it:

```
app.constant("obj", "11111");

app.config(["$stateProvider", function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("App", {
        url: "",
        controller: "appCtrl",
        templateUrl: "app.html",
        resolve: {
            initData: ["obj", function (obj) {
                return obj;
            }]
        }
    })
}])
```

Comment: I know it. but i do not understand why i can not declare a constant within resolve or controller. I found the **value** that can be used instead of the **constant**.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

```
resolve: {
    initData: ["$q", "$timeout", function ($q, $timeout) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function () {
            $provide.value("SECTOR_COLORS", "Angular JS");
            deferred.resolve();
        }, 2000);
        return deferred.promise;
    }]
}
```